# How to get a string in ObjectId in MongoDB v3.6?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation query whose MongoDB repsonse is :

```
_id: ObjectId('5e822d6c87502b3a9b751786')
```

I would like to get the string inside the ObjectId which is `5e822d6c87502b3a9b751786`.

---

**[ Problem ]**

I have searched this question but so far there are only three operators that are capable to do this, namely `$toString`, `$toObjectId`, and `$convert` :

```
$project: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
}
```

```
$project: {
      _id: {
        $toObjectId: "$_id"
      }
}
```

```
$project: {
      _id: {
        $convert: {
          input: "$_id"
          to: "string"
        }
      }
}
```

**MongoDB v3.6 does not support them** if I am not mistaken.
Is there any workaround in MongoDB v3.6 to get a string inside an ObjectId?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you run an End-of-life version of MongoDB? https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy/lifecycles

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It is a legacy project and unfortunately there's nothing much I can do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MongoDB v3.6, as `$toString` and `$convert` is not available until v4.0, you may need to resort to JS/application-level access to the `_id`.

```js
db.testCollection.insertMany([
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e822d6c87502b3a9b751786")
}]);

db.testCollection.find().forEach( doc => { 
    // put your logic for process here
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc._id))
});
```

output:

```
"5e822d6c87502b3a9b751786"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add [ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75187390/14418391) after some findings.

**Having defined a model** in the app, here are some workaround that worked for me:

1. Promises

```
const TestCollection = require('../models/testCollection');

function getStringInObjectId() {
  TestCollection.find().then(t => {
    t.forEach(doc => {
      // Put some logic here...
      console.log('string in ObjectId :', JSON.stringify(doc._id));
    });
  });
}
```

2. Async/Await

```
const TestCollection = require('../models/testCollection');

async function getStringInObjectId() {
  const t = await TestCollection.find();
  t.forEach(doc => {
    // Put some logic here...
    console.log('string in ObjectId :', JSON.stringify(doc._id));
  });
}
```

---

Same goes to aggregation :

1. Promises

```
const TestCollection = require('../models/testCollection');

function getStringInObjectId() {
  TestCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'name': 'marc' } }, // <- { 'name': 'marc' } is just an example, feel free to change it
    // Put some stages here if required...
  ]).then(t => {
    console.log('string in ObjectId : ', t[0]._id.toString());
  });
}
```

2. Async/Await

```
const TestCollection = require('../models/testCollection');

async function getStringInObjectId() {
  const t = await TestCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'name': 'marc' } }, // <- { 'name': 'marc' } is just an example, feel free to change it
    // Put some stages here if required...
  ]);
  console.log('string in ObjectId : ', t[0]._id.toString());
}
```

Either `JSON.stringify()` or `toString()` can be used to convert it to string. Feel free to correct variable names.